# Finding difference between two dataframes by a column is not working

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, comparison

I have two large datasets in newdata & olddata dataframes with ID as primary column key & 30 other columns.
While most of the IDs are common between new & old, there are few old IDs that are deleted & not present in new and vice versa, new IDs are added in New that were not present in Old.

now, i am trying to put label to all 3 categories as Common, New & Old and while New & Common are working fine, i am not having so much success with Old. Not Sure what am i missing and any pointers would be appreciated

```
commonIDs<-data.frame(intersect(old_data$IDs,new_data$IDs))

#New Ids
added <- NULL
added <- new_data[!new_data$IDs %in% commonIDs$IDs,]
added <- data.frame(Remarks ="New", added)


#Deleted IDs
deleted <- NULL
deleted <- old_data[!old_data$IDs %in% commonIDs$IDs,]
```

I also tried another approach but still not luck

```
new <- data.frame(new_data[is.na(match(new_data$IDs,commonIDs$IDs)),])
old <- data.frame(old_data[is.na(match(old_data$IDs,commonIDs$IDs)),])
```

Comment: Your code looks fine - can you make your example reproducible? How sure are you that it's not working? Perhaps you don't actually have any old IDs that are not present in the `new_data`.

Comment: As a side note, `added <- NULL` and `deleted <- NULL` don't do anything - you can delete those lines.

Comment: A way to just see the deleted IDs quickly would be `setdiff(old_data$IDs, new_data$IDs)`. If that gives `character(0)` or `numeric(0)` (or whatever your ID class is), then all the IDs from `old_data` are in `new_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also consider trying a package developed around this use case.

Using @r2evans' data:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
dat1 <- dat[-(3:4),,drop=FALSE]
dat2 <- dat[-(6:10),,drop=FALSE]
```

We could run:

```
library(waldo)
compare(dat1, dat2)
```

and get this output (pasted as picture to retain color formatting), which shows us that `dat1` is missing the data and rownames of rows 3-4, and `dat2` is missing those for rows 6-10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
dat1 <- dat[-(3:4),,drop=FALSE]
dat2 <- dat[-(6:10),,drop=FALSE]
```

A full-join operation:

```r
merged <- merge(transform(dat1, dat1=T), transform(dat2, dat2=T), by = "id", all = TRUE)
merged
#    id dat1 dat2
# 1   1 TRUE TRUE
# 2   2 TRUE TRUE
# 3   3   NA TRUE
# 4   4   NA TRUE
# 5   5 TRUE TRUE
# 6   6 TRUE   NA
# 7   7 TRUE   NA
# 8   8 TRUE   NA
# 9   9 TRUE   NA
# 10 10 TRUE   NA
```

So we can easily:

```r
with(merged, ifelse(is.na(dat1), "In2", ifelse(is.na(dat2), "In1", "Common")))
#  [1] "Common" "Common" "In2"    "In2"    "Common" "In1"    "In1"    "In1"    "In1"    "In1"
```